# Optimal Path in a Graph with Node and Edge Weights

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, complexity-theory, np

Consider the following Directed graph with Node and Edge Weights.
[image: A bidigraph]

Is there a non NP-Hard algorithm to find out the path of maximal score, where

```
score = sum(node weights) - sum(edge weights)
```

For the example graph, maximal score path is along path A -> B -> C -> D. Maximal score being 164 ((77 + 27 + 32 + 84) - (44 + 12 + 0)).

Comment: @ShridharRKulkarni I think any DFS implementation will be at-least O(N!). I'm looking for something that's of polynomial complexity.

Comment: @ShridharRKulkarni how dis could work in this scenario?

Comment: While it's true that runtime complexity of DFS is O(V+E), If you'd like to iterate over all possible paths using DFS, the complexity is factorial.

Comment: Just to clarify: the cycle (B, C, D) has score (27 + 32 + 84) - (89 + 12 + 0) > 0, so one could increase the score arbitrarily by walking this cycle. Are you looking for only simple paths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that there isn't any algorithm that can find the solution in polynomial time, I'm trying to prove that this problem is NP-Hard because we can reduce it to [the longest path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem) and the longest path problem can be reduced to it.

Here's my attempt (assuming that both edge and node weights are positive):

1. Reduction from this problem to the longest path problem:

This problem can be reduced to the longest path problem by splitting each node A into two nodes A-IN and A-OUT, such that these nodes doesn't have any weights, we link incoming edges to A into A-IN, and outgoing edges from A to A-OUT, and add an edge between A-IN and A-OUT with weight equal to -1 times node A's original weight. Now to find a solution to the problem you have to find the longest path in this graph.

2. Reduction from the longest path problem to this problem (and here I'm not sure that I didn't do any mistakes):

The longest path problem can be reduced to this problem by taking each negative weight edge E between two nodes A and B and create a virtual node AB in the middle of it, we remove E from the graph then add an edge from A to AB with weight 0, and an edge from AB to B with weight 0, and give node AB weight equal to -1 times the weight of the original E.

So that was hopefully a proof that you can solve the longest path problem by reducing it to your problem, so if there is a polynomial time solution to your problem then P = NP.

Comment: It's a good answer, but seems like it can be simplified. To show the decision problem is NP-complete: First, it's in NP because we can check the weight of a candidate solution in linear time. To reduce longest path (which is usually stated using only edge weights) to this problem: negate all edge weights, set all node weights to 0.